# findViewById returns null if used outside OnCreateView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Why does this give an error?

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
        // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
        // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
        // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
        // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
        // below that sets the article text.
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            // Set article based on argument passed in
            updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
        } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
            // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
            updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    public void updateArticleView(int position) {
        TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
        article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
        outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
    }
}
```

The line that fails is:

```
article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
```

because article is null. So:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article)
```

is returning null.

However, if I set article in onCreateView like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);;
    article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);

    return view;
}
```

and change updateArticle like this:

```
public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the view that you are inflating from the block

```
    onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //Previous code
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
```

then you can call it anywhere else in your code to get the view like this:

```
    view.findViewById(R.id.view_searched);
```

instead of :

```
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_searched);
```

Comment: I have to mention that the code is from a google example in the basic Android tutorials.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

Probably instead of calling

```
TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
```

You should call

```
TextView article = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.article);
```

Comment: I tried that before, doesn't work either. I have to mention that the code is from a google example in the basic Android tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the textview is in the fragment and not the activity.
The getActivity() returns the activity and not the fragment. Thus it is unable to find the textView local to the fragment.

Whereas in onCreateView, you're mentioning view.findViewById() where the 'view' is the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing activity's context in fragment and its not necessary that activity's creation is completed by that time. If you have to call this outside the onCreate then call it in OnActivityCreated method of your fragment.

But it seems that your textview is in fragment and not in the activity

Answer (score 0):

Because `findViewById` is done to get the id on a View Object, not in an `Activity` Object. When you instantiate a `Fragment` you create a view with `onCreateView` method:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);;
 article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
 return view;
```

You are searching that id in your View (with container is `R.layout.article_view`).

If you do `getActivity.findViewById()` there is no view to find by your id.

Comment: I have to mention that the code is from a google example in the basic Android tutorials.

Comment: Yeah but your view is in your fragment not in your activity right?